# Joomla SEFLink does not work after AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, sef

Help a newbie. sketched out the sample code, and I can not make seflink work correctly after Ajax request.

**ajax request code:**

```
var timer_search = 300;
var max_symbols = 1;
jQuery("#jshop_search").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
  var count_symbols = jQuery(this).val();
  var count_search = jQuery(this).val().length;
  if(count_search >= max_symbols) {
    go_search(count_symbols, count_search);
  }
});

function go_search(count_symbols, count_search) {
var request;
        request = jQuery.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/components/com_jshopping/controllers/ajax_search.php',
            data:{check: count_symbols},
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery('#results').html(data);
                }
        }); 
}
```

**ajax_search.php code:**

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') or die;
define('_JEXEC', 1) or die();

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))));
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$path = JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS;

require($path . 'defines.php');
require($path . 'framework.php');
if (!file_exists(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/jshopping.php')){
    JError::raiseError(500,"Please install component \"joomshopping\"");
} 
require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/factory.php'); 
require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/jtableauto.php');
require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/tables/config.php'); 
require_once (JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/functions.php');
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise(); 
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
$jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$lang = "name_ru-RU";
$search_array = explode(" ", $_POST['check']);
foreach($search_array as $search_sql) {
    $sql = $sql."%".$search_sql."%";
}
$limit = 10;

$sql_get = "SELECT DISTINCT(category_id)
FROM #__jshopping_products_to_categories";
$db->setQuery($sql_get);
$result_get = $db->loadRowList();
foreach ($result_get as $result) {
    $results_cat = $results_cat.$result[0].",";
}
$results_cat = trim($results_cat, ',');

$sql_get = "SELECT category_id, `".$lang."` FROM #__jshopping_categories
WHERE category_id IN (".$results_cat.") AND category_publish='1' AND 
`".$lang."` LIKE \"$sql\" ORDER BY `".$lang."` ASC LIMIT 10";   
$db->setQuery($sql_get);
$result_get = $db->loadRowList();

foreach($result_get as $category)
{
    if($limit > 0) {?> 
        <a href='<?php print SEFLink('/index.php?
option=com_jshopping&controller=category&task=view&category_id='
.$category[0].'', 1); ?>'><?php print $category[1]."<br>"; ?></a>
<?php
    $limit--;
} else {
    break;
}
}
```

Getting link like (index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=category&task=view&category_id=125&Itemid=121)

Help please :)

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).